# Lossless SQLite FTS5 search of a substring

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts5

Using a FTS5 virtual table returns nothing for **post**fix searches.

It only can search for the entire word tokens, or for the prefixes of the word tokens if I append `*` to the search.

For example, it does not find `qwerty.png` row, if I search for `werty`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files (name TEXT, id INTEGER);
INSERT INTO files (name, id) VALUES ('qwerty.png', 1),  ('asdfgh.png', 2);
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS names USING FTS5(name);
INSERT INTO names (name) SELECT name FROM files;
```

```
SELECT *
FROM names
WHERE name MATCH 'werty';
```

It only works for prefix searches (`qwerty`, `qwer*`, `qwe*`, ...).

I can't use `*` at the start of the search (`*werty`), since it produces an error.

---

Is possibly to make the indexed text search working as if I would use

```
SELECT *
FROM names
WHERE name like '%wert%';
```

?

I just want to have the fast search for a substring without the full table scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try the [**experimental** trigram tokenizer](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#the_experimental_trigram_tokenizer)

> When using the trigram tokenizer, a query or phrase token may match any sequence of characters within a row, not just a complete token.

Comment: Yeah, it works exactly as I asked. Although, the virtual table size is doubled in comparison with the default `tokenize="unicode61"`. For example, the table with only text column _(and rowid)_ takes 55 MB, the virtual FTS5 table additionally takes 100 MB with `unicode61` tokenizer, or 200 MB with `trigram` tokenizer.